# How do I wait for a coroutine to finish without scheduling it at the same time?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a list of coroutines, I put them in a queue. At some point, someone else will run them. I want to wait for a specific sublist of the coroutines to finish.

```py
coro_list = [coro1(), coro2(), ...]
queue = asyncio.Queue()
for c in coro_list:
    queue.put_nowait(c)

# someone else will read from the queue and await the coroutines...

# here, I want to wait, for example, only for coro_list[2:6] to finish
```

Comment: Are `coro1`, `coro2` etc. your own or external functions? How about the queue consumer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the coroutine functions you want to have run and then wait for are from an external library, you can write a *wrapper* for them and pass it an [`Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) object. The wrapper will then `await` the coroutine and subsequently [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event.set) the event flag. In your main coroutine you can then simply [`wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event.wait) for all the flags being set.

Example:

```py
from asyncio import Event, create_task, gather, run, sleep
from collections.abc import Awaitable


async def coro(i: int) -> None:
    await sleep(i)
    print(f"coroutine {i} finished")


async def runner(*awaitables: Awaitable[None]) -> None:
    await gather(*awaitables)


async def wrapper(awaitable: Awaitable[None], done_flag: Event) -> None:
    await awaitable
    done_flag.set()


async def main() -> None:
    done_flag_1, done_flag_2 = Event(), Event()
    coroutines = [
        wrapper(coro(1), done_flag_1),
        wrapper(coro(2), done_flag_2),
        coro(3),
    ]
    runner_task = create_task(runner(*coroutines))
    await gather(done_flag_1.wait(), done_flag_2.wait())
    print("Done waiting for coroutines 1 & 2")
    await runner_task


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(main())
```

Output:

```
coroutine 1 finished
coroutine 2 finished
Done waiting for coroutines 1 & 2
coroutine 3 finished
```

If *you* control the `coro` or `runner` functions, you may not need the `wrapper` at all. Instead, depending on how exactly you want to schedule/execute the coroutines, you could for example turn them into `Task`s and use [`Task.add_done_callback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.add_done_callback) to set the flag.

Comment: So it seems there is really no way to wait on an arbitrary coroutine to finish

Comment: @Zerkala No way without actually `await`ing it that I know of.